# SassError: This file is already being loaded. @import '~src/css/quasar.variables.scss', 'quasar/src/css/variables.sass'; src\css\quasar.variables.scss

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I am using the quasar framework and while compiling the project I'm getting the above error

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: This file is already being loaded.
  ╷
1 │ @import '~src/css/quasar.variables.scss', 'quasar/src/css/variables.sass';
  │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  src\css\quasar.variables.scss 1:9  root stylesheet
```

Comment: Since CSS is not scoped like JS modules, importing a file once in a project is usually enough

Comment: but I have not imported anywhere for it

Comment: Are you importing quasar anywhere else?

Comment: i thik it could be

Comment: It's likely that importing quasar somewhere else also imports the variables

Comment: i am only importing  import { Notify } from "quasar";
to the boot/axios.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235209/discussion-between-swatantra-and-evolutionxbox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while routing I was passing the wrong path.

Before

```
Route.setViewResolver( component => require( "src/" + component ).default );
```

After

```
Route.setViewResolver( component => require( "src/pages/" + component ).default );
```

I have missed the path where to pass the component "src/pages/"